# Why we use console.table method?

Tags: javascript, debugging, error-handling, console

I know one of the most basic debugging tools in JavaScript is `console.log()`. The console comes with several other useful methods that can add to a developer’s debugging toolkit.
but 
I'm pretty confused about `console.table()` method. Is anyone explain?

Comment: There's not much to say beyond what's in the docs. It prints stuff in a table, which makes things easier to read, if you have something that's tabular in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Console Object:**
The console object gives you access to the browser’s console. It lets you output strings, arrays, and objects that help debug your code. The console is part of the window object, and is supplied by the Browser Object Model (BOM).

**There are four different ways of outputting a message to the console:**

1. log
2. info
3. warn
4. error

while
**there is another method that is:**

***`console.table()`***

let me explain
The table method displays an array or object as a table.

```
console.table(['Javascript', 'PHP', 'Perl', 'C++']);
```

**example:**

```
const superhero = { 
    firstname: 'Peter',
    lastname: 'Parker',
}
console.table(superhero);
```

Comment: At the very least I'd have expected a screenshot. Saying *"The table method displays an array or object as a table."* is kind of obvious given the method name and doesn't add much value in itself IMO.